# Narrow to subtree with org-velocity

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I would like to use org-velocity as my primary means of navigating large `.org` files but with the following changes:

1. After running a search in org-velocity, I would like the buffer to automatically narrow to that subtree, once I make my selection.
2. Org-velocity should run its search against the entire file, even if the buffer is narrowed.

For part (1) I think something like this should work:

`(add-hook 'org-follow-link-hook (lambda () (org-narrow-to-subtree)))`

But this is not the right hook. Not sure how to approach (2). Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: For (2) you could use an around advice with `save-restriction` and `widen`.

Comment: Tobias. Thanks for your comment! Can you elaborate on this a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I have a complete solution!

1. Make sure you have this fork of org-velocity installed:

   https://github.com/Fuco1/org-velocity
2. Open your org-velocity.el file and replace lines 763-765 with this:

   ```
   (progn
     (with-current-buffer (org-velocity-match-buffer)
       (kill-buffer-and-window))
     (org-narrow-to-subtree)
     (show-all))))))
   ```

   The additional code tells org-velocity to first narrow the buffer to the selected subtree and secondly to expand that node.
3. Put this code somewhere in your search path (init.el, .emacs, etc.)

   ```
   (defadvice org-velocity (around search-all activate)
      "Widen for search with org-velocity"
      (widen)
      ad-do-it)
   ```

   And that's it!

Thank you Tobias, Paul and Matúš for walking me through this!!

Take care,

-Adam

Answer (score 3):

I am writing a partial answer for part (2) of the question since the following does not fit nicely into a comment. Note, that I do not use `org-velocity`. So, the following is not really tested.
`save-restriction` saves the current narrowing to the org-subtree and `widen` removes this narrowing temporarily during the search. To see exactly how it works read the help for the functions `save-restriction` and `widen` with <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> and consult the info <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> for `elisp` and there the Section "Advising functions".

```lisp
(defadvice org-velocity (around search-all activate)
  "Widen for search with org-velocity"
  (save-restriction
    (widen)
    ad-do-it
    ))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Tobias!! I'd make one change though: remove save-restriction. Otherwise org-velocity won't be able to navigate outside of the current node (assuming that the document starts out narrowed to this point).

Comment: @Adam Have you tried it? For me it looked good. You get a buffer with matches can choose one get a new buffer with point at the match. If you are done you press C-c C-c and are where you started (including the old restriction). I do not know if that is the wanted behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it. Do this: open an org file and narrow to say * Heading 100, then C-c v to run org-velocity and search for another heading, say Heading 32. Org-velocity finds this so you hit [RET]. But if save-restriction is left in, the function prevents you from navigating away from Heading 100 (since you had previously narrowed to this point). So all I did was take your function and remove "save-restriction" and it works great.

Comment: One other thing, you may be using a different version of org-velocity. This is the one I'm using: https://github.com/Fuco1/org-velocity