# Orgmode - get completion on tags from current file when buffer is narrowed to a subtree

Tags: emacs, tags, elisp, org-mode

Suppose you are working in an org-mode file and have narrowed your buffer to the current subtree:

```
* My great heading
  blah, blah, blah... etc.
```

You now want to add some tags to your heading. So you hit `C-c C-q` then `[TAB]` to checkout what's available. But... nothing shows up!

This is because org-mode only offers completion on tags that are currently displayed in the buffer!

What to do...?

Answer (score 0):

The solution comes from an answer by Tobias [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822973/narrow-to-subtree-with-org-velocity) (thanks Tobias!).

Save this code somewhere in your search path (init.el, .emacs, etc.) and Org-mode will now search your entire file for tags to choose from:

```
(defadvice org-set-tags (around search-all activate)
  "Widen for search with org-set-tags"
  (save-restriction
    (widen)
    ad-do-it
    ))
```

Good luck!